# PHP MySQL date greater than

Tags: php, mysql, database

Ok...

So I have a string which in this case checks the date with the PHP date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
I want this to check with a database row, if it's larger than.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM date WHERE '$this->dateClose' < start_time AND '$this->dateOpen' < end_time";
```

It's in a loop so it will print everything which has a start_time less than dateClose and the opposite for dateOpen and end_time. But it doesn't work, please help.

Comment: What's in the `$this->dateClose` and `$this->dateOpen`? and what format are `start_time` and `end_time` fields?

Comment: Try this `$sql="SELECT * FROM date WHERE {$this->dateClose} < start_time AND {$this->dateOpen} < end_time";`

Comment: start_time = 2014-11-01 21:00
end_time = 2014-11-02 19:00

$this->dateOpen = 2014-11-01 20:00
$this->dateClose = 2014-11-02 18:00

Comment: So your query is `SELECT * FROM date WHERE '2014-11-02 18:00' < '2014-11-01 21:00' AND '2014-11-01 20:00' < '2014-11-02 19:00'`. **'2014-11-02 18:00' < '2014-11-01 21:00'** is false.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `WHERE field operator value_to_match` and change your value in proper format to match `datetime`

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM date WHERE start_time > '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->dateClose))."' AND end_time < '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($this->dateOpen))."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM date WHERE '".$this->dateClose."' < start_time AND '".$this->dateOpen."' < end_time";
```

Answer (score 0):

For the given values

```
start_time = 2014-11-01 21:00 end_time = 2014-11-02 19:00 
$this->dateOpen = 2014-11-01 20:00 $this->dateClose = 2014-11-02 18:00
```

geting no rows from sql is OK. There is no valid row for your condition

```
WHERE '2014-11-02 18:00' < start_time AND '2014-11-01 20:00' < end_time'
```

the `'2014-11-02 18:00' < '2014-11-01 21:00'` part is false. 
You have to rethink what you want to get from your sql.